# how to access user feed/posts using android facebook sdk

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to read a facebook logged in user feed/stories published by him/her or from friends pages or groups etc visible on their wall.

I was able to accomplish login, reading user posts. But i was not able to figure out how i read the posts/ feed from other users which we normally see from friends or pages or groups when they open facebook proprietary app.

The only workaround i can think of is reading friends list and their posts and showing them on current logged in user posts. Not sure why i get the same result when i use  me/feed or me/posts.

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("fields", "message,created_time,id,full_picture,status_type,source,comments.summary(true),likes.summary(true)");
    params.putString("limit", "100");
    /* make the API call */
    new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/feed", params, HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    /* handle the result */
                    System.out.println("Festival Page response::" + String.valueOf(response.getJSONObject()));

                    try {
                        JSONObject jObjResponse = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response.getJSONObject()));
                        System.out.println(jObjResponse);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented on the [`User`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user) object of the Graph api. And, as of the Graph API v2.6, there is basically one main endpoint from which you get posts from a user.

- [`/{user-id}/feed`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user/feed) includes all the things that a user might see on their own profile feed; this includes, e.g., shared links, checkins, photos and status updates. This also includes posts made by friends on the user's profile.

The following endpoints return subsets of the above:

- `/{user-id}/posts` returns the posts created by the user (on their own profile or the profile of a friend), and it may include any kind of content such as shared links, checkins, photos and status updates.
- `/{user-id}/tagged` returns the posts created by friends and shared on the users's profile.

By default each returned post only includes the story field with a textual description of the post. But you can use the `?fields=...` parameter to request as many Post fields as you want.

You'll need the user_posts permission for any of these to work.

*The following endpoints are deprecated:*

- [`/{user-id}/statuses`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/statuses) returns only status updates posted by the user on their own profile. [removed after Graph API v2.3]
- [`/{user-id}/home`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/home) returns a stream of all the posts created by the user and their friends, i.e. what you usually find on the “News Feed” of Facebook. [removed after Graph API v2.3]

Comment: Thanks for the info. Whats the workaround for the last point. That's what i want to achieve which is News Feed /{user-id}/home ?

Comment: Feed - `/{user-id}/feed` - gives you the user's feed - meaning the posts he sees when he is visiting facebook (friends important posts) - notice that facebook filters only things it's algorithm marks as significant to the user and not everything.

Tagged - `/{user-id}/tagged` - the posts created by friends and shared on the users' profile.

Posts - `/{user-id}/posts` - what the user posts - including on other people's walls

Comment: Not sure why for me the the me/feed only gives my posts not the posts from my friends.

Comment: Check if you have required `User Data Permissions`

Comment: private static final String[] PERMISSIONS =
            new String[] {"public_profile","user_friends","user_posts"};

Comment: You can optionally include `user_status` also depending on your requirements.

Comment: For me results for `/{user-id}/feed` and `/{user-id}/posts` are different. If i tell you what is different, `Feed` also includes those posts in which i'm tagged.

Comment: _"Not sure why for me the the me/feed only gives my posts not the posts from my friends"_ - because the decision whether a 3rd-party app can see their posts is up to your friends. They would need to login to your app and grant it permission first.